# How is my question off topic when I'm asking what would be the outcome of a particular experiment and what would the results mean?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, non-mainstream-physics

My question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772105/365056) was recently closed marked as off topic and not main stream physics and serially downvoted with no one even understanding the question in my opinion.

I don't think this is fair.

I have asked two points:

1. Has this "loophole" been addressed until now?
2. What would happen if the said experiment is performed, and what would the possible results mean?

The answer could be very easily:

1. Yes or No or we don't think this is a loophole, here's why.
2. Such and such would happen if you do this experiment; here's why and this is what it means.

Instead it has been closed as non-mainstream physics, which is unfair.

How can I get this question restored?

Comment: there is no such thing as FTL communication in mainstream physics , instantaneous or not.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Maybe I should have worded it differently. I have explained it in my question. the diameter of the Universe(46.1 billion light years) is larger than the age of the Universe(13.8 billion years).It is possible because space itself is expanding, technically not making it as FTL. But effectively the distance between two objects increase faster than the speed of light allows. In the same way if the space between electrons is stretched then "FTL" seeming communication can happen.

Comment: Also it is a two pronged question. My other oart of the question is still valid. What happens if this experiment is conducted?? Like physically what happens? Is the correlation violated?? Or not?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero there is literally a paper in arxiv discussing this. How is this not mainstream?? https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0614

Comment: If what you have is *one* paper from 10years ago, it is *definitely*. it mainstream.  Don’t tell me how you should have worded things.  Go back, edit your post, and explain how it is mainstream, and take yto heart the advise of @Buzz

Comment: @ZeroTheHero that I will do. But I see this as an unproductive way to conduct stack exchange. Oh you have a question?? Are there 10 papers in the last five years published regarding your question?? Is it the content and conclusion of a standard physcis text book? No, then go away. This is not physics, this is some cult based ad populum non sense. If it was just wording then an edit could have been suggested instead of marking as off topic and closing it.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero yeah let's shut down all these kinds of discussions https://youtu.be/9-jIplX6Wjw

Comment: @ZeroTheHero https://www.sciencealert.com/faster-than-light-travel-could-work-within-einstein-s-physics-astrophysicist-shows

Comment: @ZeroTheHero https://futurism.com/the-byte/paper-claims-faster-than-light-travel-is-possible

Answer (score 5):

Your question posits the possibility of faster-than-light communication.  That typically means a question is not concerning with mainstream physics.  I say "typically" here, because there is a small but significant literature looking at possible local violations of special relativity.  This is useful, for example, for understanding and quantifying the results of the current generation of updated Michelson-Morley experiments.  In fact, it is something I work on myself.  However, it is a fairly technical field, and mainstream work in this area has to be very careful about mathematical definitions and methods; sloppy treatments tend to descend into self-contradiction pretty quickly.  So it is possible to ask questions about, say, how well the possibility of faster-than-light signaling in various experiments has been experimentally constrained, but useful questions of that nature generally require a much more sophisticate treatment that the one in your question.

Moreover, the question specifically talks about signaling that is superluminal but not instantaneous.  However, that turns out to be an illusory distinction in relativity.  The very first thing that Einstein showed in his first 1905 special relativity paper was that the invariance of the speed of light (that, as observed in the Michelson-Morley experiment, the speed of light is observed to be the same by all observers, regardless of their own velocities) meant that different observers would not generally agree on whether two events were simultaneous.  What this means for faster-than-light travel or communication is that while one observer may see signals being sent faster than light, others will see signals being sent instantaneously (that is, with infinite apparent speed), and still others will see them going backwards in time.  So it is difficult to see how your proposal for faster-than-light but not instantaneous communication could be at all consistent with what we understand about relativistic physics.

Comment: My question addresses all these doubts and is main stream. I have clearly explained it when I said the diameter of the Universe(46.1 billion light years) is larger than the age of the Universe(13.8 billion years).

Comment: How is this possible??? It is possible because space itself is expanding, technically not making it as FTL. But effectively the distance between two objects increase faster than the speed of light allows. In the same way if the space between electrons is stretched then "FTL" seeming communication can happen.

Comment: Also it is a two pronged question. My other oart of the question is still valid. What happens if this experiment is conducted?? Like physically what happens? Is the correlation violated?? Or not?

Comment: @HariKumar are you saying your question lacks focus?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero hmm not exactly. I'm saying my question has two interrelated sub questions.